# Does CString preserve GetLastError code?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, mfc, getlasterror

I need to post some debugging information into a log using MFC's [CString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688(v=vs.60).aspx), but I can't seem to find if it preserves error code set by the last WinAPI (and retrievable with [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx))?

**EDIT**: Here's a code example of a simplified version of what I'm currently doing in my existing project:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(strFilePath, ...);
if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    logError(collectDebuggerInfo(strFilePath));
}

void logError(LPCTSTR pStrDesc)
{
    int nLastError = ::GetLastError();
    CString str;
    str.Format(L"LastError=%d, Description: %s", nLastError, pStrDesc);

    //Add 'str' to the logging file...
}

CString collectDebuggerInfo(LPCTSTR pFilePath)
{
    int nLastError = ::GetLastError();
    CString str;

    str.Format(L"Debugging info for file: \"%s\"", pFilePath);

    ::SetLastError(nLastError);
    return str;   //RETURNING CString -- will it overwrite the last error?
}
```

Comment: "It" is a *type* - it doesn't and cannot preserve anything, or do otherwise.

Comment: It isn't likely that the methods of `CString` preserve the error code.  Some of the methods make API calls (via `new` or `malloc`) and it would be very surprising if they had code to save the error code because this isn't something `CString` would concern itself with.  It's at the wrong abstraction level.

Comment: OK. Good point. Thank you both. But how would I preserve the GetLastError code? For instance, if my logging method returns CString variable I can't just save GetLastError code and do SetLastError before returning CString, can I?

Comment: You can preserve GetLastError code in a DWORD. What does CString have to do with it?

Comment: Seems like the concern is whether or not using a CString could overwrite the error code.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP: Maybe you should read first before posting? As I said above, what if I want to preserve GetLastError in a method that returns CString.

Comment: Rather than trying to make `collectDebuggerInfo` last-error safe, you might need to write a function (or macro) `logError_collectDebuggerInfo` that does the equivalent of `logError(collectDebuggerInfo())` safely.

Comment: @MGaz: in particular whether *returning* a CString can change the last error code.  I think in the example code shown the CString copy constructor will be implicitly invoked, is that right?

Comment: Returning a `CString` invokes the copy constructor, which could affect `GetLastError`. (For example, if there is a per-thread `CString` cache, the call to `TlsGetValue` will destroy `GetLastError`.) In general, there are no guarantees that any function preserves `GetLastError` on success.

Comment: In the example you show it would be more robust to cache a "last error" code in your own member variable (or global) rather than try to guess whether it's safe to use `SetLastError` and `GetLastError`.

Comment: Why not pass the value of `GetLastError` into your logging function when you call it? `GetLastError` is only guaranteed to be meaningful immediately after the call that returns failure, so it's at that point that you should save the error code.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I don't think that would work, because IIRC function parameters aren't evaluated in any particular order, so the call to `GetLastError` might be evaluated *after* the call to `collectDebuggerInfo`.

Comment: `logError(collectDebuggerInfo(strFilePath, ::GetLastError()))` can't possibly evaluate `GetLastError` after either of the other calls.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Is there a way for me to override CString's copy constructor to make it preserve last error?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: ooh, that gave me an idea; see my answer.  Note, however, that once you've solved the problem of passing the error code from `collectDebuggerInfo` to `logError`, you no longer need to make the error code one of the arguments.

Comment: You know what you are supposed to do. Call GetLastError immediately. There's nothing more to say. Start designing with that rule as something that you do not break.

Answer (score 1):

One convenient solution would be to define a class that contains both a CString and a last error code, then overload `logError` and redefine `collectDebuggerInfo` something like this:

```
void logError(StringWithEmbeddedErrorCode instr)
{
    LPCTSTR pStrDesc = instr.str;
    SetLastError(instr.nLastError);
    logError(pStrDesc);
}

StringWithEmbeddedErrorCode collectDebuggerInfo(LPCTSTR pFilePath)
{
    int nLastError = ::GetLastError();
    CString str;

    str.Format(L"Debugging info for file: \"%s\"", pFilePath);

    return StringWithEmbeddedErrorCode(str, nLastError);
}
```

This way you don't have to change the code that invokes the error handling functions.