# Why Microsoft Error Message uses the word "Token"?

Tags: winapi, token, getlasterror

I purposely set a bad path for a `CreateDirectory` call so that my exception handling code would execute:

[image: Microsoft Error Text]

I am not sure if this is off topic, but you might have more experience with this. Why is the error text:

> An attempt was made to reference a **token** that does not exist.

Why are they using the word **token** instead of **file** or **folder**?

I will close the question if off topic.

The return value of `GetLastError` is: **123**

According to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-):

> `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`
>
> `123 (0x7B)`
>
> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Now **that message** makes sense. So why is my Windows 10 showing the other message?

Comment: which concrete api call fail ? with with which arguments ? in which context (user, localsystem, etc ?) you run ?

Comment: @RbMm I added a `*` in folder name making the folder invalid (which is in the user application data folder).

Comment: which concrete error code ? `ERROR_NO_TOKEN` ?

Comment: @RbMm `GetLastError` returns `123`.

Comment: 123 - this is `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` which is clear if you use `*` in folder name, but why in this case you show `ERROR_NO_TOKEN` text in message box ?

Comment: *The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect* must be your error text, if you get `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`. your screenshot is confusing

Comment: *So why is my Windows 10 showing the other message?* - but this is you show this message. how you show it ? or this message show from another place. this is message *An attempt was made to reference a token that doesn't exist. This is typically done by referencing the token associated with a thread when the thread is not impersonating a client.*

Comment: @RbMm Got it sorted. I had to call `GetlastError` **first** and then pass that into my handler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does CString preserve GetLastError code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855841/does-cstring-preserve-getlasterror-code)

Comment: Classic mistake: Calling `GetLastError` too late. There are *at least* 2 operations in between the call to `CreateDirectory` returning, and the `CWin32FileError`'s c'tor picking up the last error code (construction and destruction of temporaries). Either one can change the calling thread's last error code. If you can use C++17, the easiest solution would be to add an init-statement to your [if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if), e.g. (`if(auto path_name{GetWorkingPath() + _T("Some literal")}; !CreateDirectory(path_name, nullptr)) { /* reuse path_name */ ...}`).

Comment: Although that, too, would still require an appropriate c'tor signature (taking a const ref as opposed to by-val). And even then, this is still very, very brittle, with lots of opportunities to fail in subtle ways. Even though that is what you are trying to avoid, it's really best to just explicitly call `GetLastError` instead of having someone else do it for you. Also, while debugging, enter a special watch (`@err,hr`) which will constantly get updated as you step through your code, and shows a human-readable representation along with it (as if you were calling `FormatMessage`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with the call to `FormatMessage`. It works as advertised. However, you aren't passing in the value 123 (`ERROR_INVALID_NAME`). You are passing 1008 ([`ERROR_NO_TOKEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-)), by accident, due to calling `GetLastError` at the wrong time. [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) has a strong requirement:

> You should call the `GetLastError` function **immediately** when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data. That is because some functions call `SetLastError` with a zero when they succeed, wiping out the error code set by the most recently failed function.

It's fairly straightforward to satisfy this in C. With C++, things get more complicated, with all the invisible code the compiler generates. The code in question apparently captures the calling thread's last error code only after it enters the `CWin32FileError` c'tor. That's too late.

Based on the assumption that `GetWorkingPath()` returns a `CString` instance by value, and `CWin32FileError` takes its arguments as `CString const&`, this is what happens behind the scenes:

```
if (!CreateDirectory(GetWorkingPath() + _T("whatever"), nullptr))
```

1. `GetWorkingPath()` constructs a temporary `CString` instance.
2. `operator+(CString const&, LPCTSTR)` constructs yet another temporary `CString` instance, concatenating both inputs.
3. `operator LPCTSTR()` is implicitly invoked on the temporary constructed in step 2.
4. `CreateDirectory` is called and returns.
5. **Important:** The destructor of the temporary created in step 2 is called.
6. **Important:** The destructor of the temporary created in step 1 is called.

Steps 5 and 6 are fatal already, potentially changing the calling thread's last error code. And yet, there's even more code getting in the way:

```
CWin32FileError e(_T("whatever"),
                  GetWorkingPath() + _T("whatever"));
```

1. **Important:** `_T("whatever")` triggers `CString`'s conversion constructor (`CString(LPCTSTR)`), producing a temporary.
2. **Important:** `GetWorkingPath()` constructs a temporary, invoking `CString`'s copy-c'tor.
3. **Important:** `operator+(CString const&, LPCTSTR)` constructs yet another temporary.
4. The `CWin32FileError` c'tor finally runs, presumably calling `GetLastError`.

This adds another 3 candidates (at least) that can modify the calling thread's last error code. To solve this, you're going to have to make sure, that *absolutely* no code runs in between a failed Windows API call and the call to `GetLastError`.

To do this, you're going to have to get rid of the temporaries, and move capturing of the last error code outside the `CWin32FileError` c'tor. A simple solution to the former would be to construct the path name up front, e.g.

```
auto path_name{ GetWorkingPath() + _T("whatever") };
auto path_name_strptr{ path_name.GetString() };
if (!CreateDirectory(path_name_strptr, nullptr))
// ...
```

(or use an init-statement in the [if statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) to limit the scope, if you are using C++17). Either way, your **very next** call must be `GetLastError` to capture the last error code while it is still meaningful. However you pass that value into `CWin32FileError`'s c'tor, or which argument types it uses, is up to you. But you cannot rely on that c'tor to capture the last error code for you.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.  I have ended up dropping the exception class, getting the error number myself, formatting it and displaying in a task dialog. This cuts out all of those overheads with invisible code.

Comment: Dropping the custom exception class is only part of the solution, and it's the part that *can* easily be fixed. You still have to deal with the other part: Mixing C++ code with the requirements of a C API. It's unfortunate that MFC doesn't offer a better error reporting story. And when you do reach out to call the Windows API, you're essentially on your own, with no (documented) guarantees provided by the framework.

Comment: I also now understand what you are saying about building the path and then passing it in as opposed to constructing it on the fly as the parameter. I will review the code.